# Regex doesn't match anything for long strings loaded from file in C++

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11

I have a plain html file with ascii encoding. I load it in a c++ sub programme in Visual C++ 2012 and I try to extract some patterns from it. But I have discovered that no match is found whatever the regex is.

I tried the programme with both cmatch and smatch, but it didn't work with the string loaded from the file.

The file contains only ascii characters and I need multiline regex support but the programme works only with the assigned strings and not with the loaded strings from files. I examined the loaded text from the file. It is loaded correctly. The problem is with the regex.

```
void findFrasi(string filename){
    fstream f;
    f.open(filename, fstream::in);
    char* ls;
    ls = (char*)malloc(1000 * 10); 
    f.get(ls, fileSize, char(255));
    std::string s(ls);

    try {
        //s= "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">";
        std::smatch cm;
        std::regex e ("([\\s|\\S]*)(http)([\\s|\\S]*)", std::regex::ECMAScript  | std::regex::icase );

        std::regex_match( s, cm, e, regex_constants::match_any );

        std::cout << "matches:" << cm.size() << std::endl;

        for (std::smatch::iterator it = cm.begin(); it!=cm.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
        if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_badrepeat)
            std::cerr << "Repeat was not preceded by a valid regular expression.\n";
        else std::cerr << "Some other regex exception happened.\n";
    }

    free(ls);
    f.close();
}
```

The exception never occurs! and I always get the output: `matches0`

By the way, I tried also other regex scripts such as std::regex::ECMAScript and they were not different.

Comment: `regex_match` tries to match the *entire* string. Use `regex_search`.

Comment: And what patterns do you need to extract?

Comment: @Grigoriy-chudnov I need to extract patterns like <td class="frase">(What I want to get)</td>. The above example is only for testing.

Comment: @Xeo regex_match works well when I assign the s variable in the programme but it fails with the string loaded from the file.

Comment: Do you have a sample file? could you upload it somewhere?

Comment: @Grigoriy-chudnov The sample file is created by fetching a webpage by curl library in c++. This is my whole code http://pastebin.com/dLQ7b2KA The files are saved in ascii, ansi DOS. It is what notepad++ says.

Comment: @Grigoriy-chudnov I have just tested http://pastebin.com/YfKQx4QG against ([\\s|\\S]*)(http.*\.com)([\\s|\\S]*) using http://regexpal.com/ and I see that it works significant

Comment: @Xeo you're right. using regex_search it finds something but it matchs only the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sregex_iterator` to get all matches.

Something like this (should run on Visual C++ 2012 with Nov2012CTP):

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string filepath = "jonny_regex_text.txt"; // the file you provided
    std::ifstream ifs(filepath.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    size_t length = static_cast<size_t>(ifs.tellg());
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    std::string text;
    text.resize(length);

    ifs.read(&text[0], length);
    ifs.close();

    std::string pattern(R"((http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*)");
    std::regex r(pattern, regex::icase);
    for (std::sregex_iterator it(text.begin(), text.end(), r), end_it; it != end_it; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->str() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code prints all URLs that you have in a text file.